# IPN Notification Verfication INVALID

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I keep getting an `INVALID` response from PayPal when sending the data back to verify it's come from them. I've read lots of other posts on SO with nothing helping so far. This is what I can verify:

1. The order of params is the same.
2. The data is the same with the exception of me prepending `cmd=_notify-validate&` to the request.

This is some quick hacky code to post the data up:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    var nvc = new NameValueCollection { {"cmd", "_notify-validate"} };
    foreach (var f in formCollectionData.AllKeys)
        nvc.Add(f, formCollectionData[f]);

    try
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        var response = client.UploadValues(_urls[payPalResponse.test_ipn], "POST", nvc);
        var result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response); //returns "INVALID"
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

`formCollectionData` is the data that is fed through to my Action (using MVC). I've verified this is correct by looking at the `Request.Form.ToString()` data.

I've tried posting using a couple of other methods but get the same `INVALID` result.

I've read about changing the language encoding in the paypal preferences to `UTF-8` but I'm using the IPN Simulator so not sure how this would apply.

I appear to be going round in circles and don't know what to do.

**EDIT**
I've just tried this from my sandbox paypal account by going into the IPN History and re-sending one and it has worked correctly. I get a status of verified back.

This means it's just the IPN Simulator that isn't working properly so I assume it's to do with the encoding. Is it possible to see / change the encoding of the simulator to UTF-8?

Comment: You might want to report the issue to PayPal at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/. Based on my experience, the IPN simulator did cause issue due to incompatible encoding in the IPN data received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered the same problem. It does seem to be an error with the simulator.

Try clearing all the date fields in the simulator so they are blank. It seems to be that some of the special characters within the form are causing issues.

This is just a bug in the IPN simulator and real IPN messages will not be affected in the same way.

Comment: I've only just tested this in the past week so apologies for the delay in marking as the answer. It did indeed resolve the issue.